# The webpage cannot be found after submit my info

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have view which name is thanks and I want to show this view after click submit , but its encounter with error like this:The webpage cannot be found 
Here is my code:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewBag.greeting = hour < 12 ? "Good Morning" : "Good Afternoon";
            return View ("MyView");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm()
        {
            return View("RsvpForm");

        }
        [HttpPost]

        public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestRespons GuestRespons)
        {
            Repository.AddResponse(GuestRespons);
            return View("Thanks", GuestRespons);

        }

    }
```

and this is my view :

```
@{Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>
        Thanks
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <h1>
            thank you,@Model.Name!
        </h1>

        @if (Model.WillAttend== true)
        {
            @:it's great that you are comming.we will see you soon.
        }
        else
    {
        @:Sorry to hear that, but Thanks for letting us to know.     
    }
    </p>
    <p >
        click <a asp-action="ListResponses">here</a> to see who is coming.
    </p> 
</body>
</html>
```

And this one is my button which should show thanks view:

```
@model FuturGoals_partyinvites_.Models.GuestRespons


@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RsvpForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-action="RcvpForm" method="post">

        <p>
            <label asp-for="Name">Your Name:</label>
            <input asp-for="Name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="Email">Your Email:</label>
            <input asp-for="Email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="phone">Your Phone:</label>
            <input asp-for="phone" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Will you come?</label>
            <select asp="WillAttend">
                <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Submit RSVP</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

well I don't know how get exception in mvc , I think problem should be with this line:

```
<button type="submit">Submit RSVP</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, for the views say what code is for what view, if possible please paste the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form action attribute value should be a valid url in your app. If you are using the form tag helper, you need to make sure you are passing the valid HttpPost action method name you want to submit to, as the `asp-action` attribute value.

In your case, your http post action method name is `RsvpForm`, But in your form you had `RcvpForm` which is not a valid action method. So fix your form tag helper to use the correct action method and now it should work.

```
<form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post">
   <!-- Your existing form elements goes here-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like:

```
    <p>
        <label asp-for="Name">Your Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label asp-for="Email">Your Email:</label>
        <input asp-for="Email" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label asp-for="phone">Your Phone:</label>
        <input asp-for="phone" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Will you come?</label>
        <select asp="WillAttend">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <button type="Button" id="submitme" data-url="@Url.Action("RsvpForm","Home")">Submit RSVP</button>
```

Ajax form like:

```
    $("#submitme").on("click", function () {

      var url = $(this).data('url');

       $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',//this can be change to get or post
                            url: url,
                            success: function (response) {
                                if (response != null && response.success) {
                                   Alert("Success");

                                    window.location.href = "/Home/ActionNameHere"; //You can redirect any action name here....
                                } else {
                                    // DoSomethingElse()

                                      Alert("something wrong");

                                }
                            }
                        });

    });
```